# Increment Existing Sequence in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, increment

I'm trying to increment an existing ID field that was generated using sequence in snowflake.

For reference here's the code & sample output:

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE id_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
;
```

**Output**

```
Id   Keyword    URL    Type              Position_Group 
1     A          A      Ad                1
2     A          B      Ad                2             
3     A          C      Organic           1           
4     A          D      Organic           2          
5     A          E      Organic           3
6     A          F      Featured_Snippet  1
```

Trying to add new data that increments on this table using sequence has not provided the desired output that I need which to increment based off of the max(Id). Tried to use ALTER SEQUENCE and use max(Id) as a variable to pass into sequence but no luck so far. Appreciate any recommendations!

**Desired Output**

```
Id   Keyword    URL    Type              Position_Group 
1     A          A      Ad                1
2     A          B      Ad                2             
3     A          C      Organic           1           
4     A          D      Organic           2          
5     A          E      Organic           3
6     A          F      Featured_Snippet  1           
--
7     A          G      Organic           4
8     A          H      Organic           5
```

Comment: how are you inserting data into the table, aka how are you using the id_sequence.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim here's how I used it 

`CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE id_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1`
;

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "serp_table" AS 
SELECT 
is.nextval AS "Id",
"Keyword",
"URL",
"Type",
"Position_Group"
FROM "serp_tmp",
table(getnextval(id_sequence)) is`

this helps build the initial table, however i run into issues when trying to increment using this sequence since it starts at 1 again

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to implement SCD and you want the surrogate keys to be incremented by 1 - each time a new record is inserted - if this is what you are looking for then I wouldn't recommend you to use sequence.

You should use "autoincrement" concept.

create or replace TABLE test_surrogate_key (
test_ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement,
test_name VARCHAR(2),
);

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Been testing this out, but how would you generate the ID instead of using a sequence in this situation? I would use nextval in sequence to generate the ID when inserting data but not sure how it would be implied here. Let me know if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you run that first line repeatedly, this is why you always get id starting at 1. Which I think you have said is a problem..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE id_sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

You CREATE table, if commented out to just be a SELECT

```
--CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE serp_table AS  
WITH serp_tmp(Keyword, URL, Type, Position_Group) as (
    SELECT * from VALUES 
    ('bob', 'https://bobthebuild.com/', 'Ad', 1),
    ('A', 'https://asite.com/', 'Organic', 1),
    ('A', 'https://aasite.com/', 'Organic', 2)
)
SELECT  
    id_sequence.nextval AS Id, 
    Keyword, URL, Type, Position_Group
FROM serp_tmp;
```

gives:

| ID | KEYWORD | URL | TYPE | POSITION_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | https://bobthebuild.com/ | Ad | 1 |
| 2 | A | https://asite.com/ | Organic | 1 |
| 3 | A | https://aasite.com/ | Organic | 2 |

second run gives:

| ID | KEYWORD | URL | TYPE | POSITION_GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | bob | https://bobthebuild.com/ | Ad | 1 |
| 5 | A | https://asite.com/ | Organic | 1 |
| 6 | A | https://aasite.com/ | Organic | 2 |

So if we don't recreate the sequence and how it's used it works how I would expect.

I guess I am still struggling to understand what your struggle is.